# GLControl: There are no components in .. that can be placed on the toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opentk

I have a problem with ["Building a Windows.Forms + GLControl based application"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160803084111/http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/glcontrol)

I use:

- MS VS 2015 14.0.25123.00 update 2
- .net Framework 4.6.01038

I have created a windows Forms project and installed from nuget:

- OpenTK.GLControl 1.1.2225 version 1.1.1589.5942

When I browse and select OpenTK.GLControl.dll, I get the message:

"There are no components in C:...\OpenTK.GLControl.dll that can be placed on the toolbox."

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Solved:
I  needed to download the .dll from github instead of using the nuget package.
Though it is quit complicate to compile oneself the .dll:
First, one needs to create a new VS project and a new local repository to clone the solution found on github.
Unfortunately,  the project openTK can't be built (three errors). Therefore OpenTK.GLControl can't be built :-(
Secondly, one needs to copy the opentk.dll found with nuget in the right folder
Thirdly, one can build OpenTK.GLControl.dll
Finally, add it manually in the toolbox.
See:
https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/37#issuecomment-219860160